# Split string to include null values represented by white space

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to split an input string that contains whitespace, but I do not want to cut it off from my split, I want to include it in my split array.  Is there a better regex or method to use in this case?

```
String data = "1     a1 b1  r5";
String splitData = data.split("\\s+");
for(String x : splitData){
  System.out.print(x + ", ");
}

Expected output: 1, , , , , ,a1, b1, , r5
```

Comment: why dont you convert to character and loop through characters

Comment: "\\s+" considers any number (1 or more) of spaces to be a single delimiter

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your methodology here. If this is all you're trying to do, it can be done much more simply:

```
String input  = "1     a1 b1  r5";
String output = input.replace(" ", ", ");
System.out.println(output);
```

The middle line simply replaces the space character, " ", with a comma followed by a space, ", ". The final output matches your requested output:

```
 1, , , , , a1, b1, , r5
```

If this is a minimal example and you actually intend to use a more complex regex, please post that regex and we can get to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an array of tokens, just use:

String[] sp = s.split( " " );

However, this will create 4 empty items after the first one, not 5.

There is 1 space between "a1" and "b1", and you expect 0 empty items there.
There are 2 spaces between "b1" and "r5" and you expect 1 empty item there.
There are 5 empty spaces between "1" and "a1". Why do you expect 5 empty items there instead of 4?

And why does your expected output not have a space after the comma in front of "a1" ?